# How to enable the workspace symbol search in the R for VSCODE extension?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am using for a long time the R in Visual Studio Code extension which uses the languageserver package, but each time I use the command to look for symbols in the workspace, it only shows the symbols in the opened files. The same problem occurs when I try to use the "Go to definition" command on a function defined in a file that is not open, the response is "No definition found".

I would like that each time a workspace is open in VSCODE, all symbols from all my files were loaded, not only the symbols for opened files because as soon as I close a file, the symbols disappears from the search options.

I see all the available options in the extesion's settings menu and I could find anything related to what I want. It is worth to mention that I have enabled the session watcher, the watch global environment and all this options that really enhance the R development experience.

Comment: add a feature request at the extension repo